# What is $\alpha$ such that the function is differentiable at every point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Determine the values of the parameter $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} |xy|^\alpha & \mbox{for } xy\neq0 \\ 0, & \mbox{for } xy=0\end{cases}$$
is differentiable at every point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us consider the function $g(x,y)=|xy|^\alpha$ and study its continuity in $(0,0)$,$(x,0)$ and $(0,y) \ \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ since these are the points in which the function "switches" between branches:

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}|xy|^\alpha = |0\cdot0|^\alpha=0$ (only for $\alpha \neq 0$, but when $\alpha = 0$ the function is evidently not continuous)

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x,0)}|xy|^\alpha = |x\cdot0|^\alpha=0$

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,y)}|xy|^\alpha = |0\cdot y|^\alpha=0$

Having concluded that the function $g$ is continuous, it follows that $f$ is continuous too, since$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}|xy|^\alpha =f(0,0);\ \ \ $ $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x,0)}|xy|^\alpha = f(x,0);\ \ \ $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,y)}|xy|^\alpha = f(0,y)$

Now for the next step, we will check the continuity of $f$'s partial derivatives:

$\frac{\textrm{d}f}{\textrm{d}x}(x,y)=(|xy|^\alpha)_{x}' = (\sqrt{(xy)}^{2\alpha})_{x}'=2\alpha(\sqrt{xy})^{2\alpha-1}\cdot (\sqrt{xy})_{x}'= 2\alpha(\sqrt{xy})^{2\alpha-1}\cdot \frac{y}{2\sqrt{xy}} = \alpha|xy|^{\alpha-1}\cdot y $

$\frac{\textrm{d}f}{\textrm{d}y}(x,y) = \alpha|xy|^{\alpha-1}\cdot x $

Notice how $\frac{\textrm{d}f}{\textrm{d}y}$ and $\frac{\textrm{d}f}{\textrm{d}x}$ are continuous only when $\alpha-1\geq0\implies \alpha \geq 1$

For now, we have that $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R^2}-((0,0)\cup(x,0)\cup(0,y)) \ \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $\alpha \geq 1$

Now, to find [differentiabilty in $(0,0)$](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4013-U98/4013-l06.pdf):

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{|xy|^\alpha}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{|xy|^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1/x^2+1/y^2}} = 0 $ (for $\alpha \geq 1$);

Differentiability in $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ is done analogously.